# Is it OK to leave some part out of the schematic if noted?

Tags: schematics

When I make schematic drawings for my projects I tend to leave things like the power switch, fuse etc. out of the schematic. I do it because I don't feel it's an important part of the circuit, one might argue that it's not actually a part of the circuit at all. And I like keeping the schematics as clean as possible.

Is this OK? Or considered bad practice? I do make a note of that I have left out, like on the image below.

[image: Fan and temperature controller with LCD circuit]

Comment: I would dock you style points for the nets named "PD0", etc.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for pointing that out, better to use the LCD pin name?

Comment: I would use "LCD" as a prefix, and then suffix 0..3, RS, E.

Comment: Agreed, that would make it more readable. I'll fix that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A schematic is an abstraction of the real circuit. We use abstractions because we want to communicate something to other people (including our future self). If what you want to tell to other people about your circuit does not involve the fuse, then it is fine to leave it out.

But if you want to use your schematic as input for making a PCB and you want the fuse on the PCB, then it is silly to leave it out in the schematic.

So it all about the intented use of your schematic.

Comment: It's a hobby project, I am sharing my circuit and code so that others might build something similar or learn from it.

Comment: So ask yourself: should they build it with fuse, or without, or don't you care? Note that your schematic doesn't show the source of Vcc. That's fine if that is a detail your readers will have to find out for themselves, maybe with different solutions. It is not OK if you want an I-hold-your-hand style guide to building your project. So it is all about *your* intent.

Comment: My goal is really to show them a working circuit, I don't see a fuse being a part of that. One question regarding the VCC, how do I indicate the voltages used? For 5V I normally just use VCC, but if a voltage regulator is involved I show e.g. 12V supply going in and VCC coming out. Do I need to indicate a correlation between VCC and 5V, if so; how?

Comment: Again, if it is totally clear for your intended audiene that Vcc must be 5V (all HD44780 LCDs I know use 5V, so to *me* it is obvious) you can leave it out, but it is a small burden to put a text sowmwhere near a Vcc symbol that mentions "+5.0V". I don't see any Vcc decoupling, now that is something I never would omit.

Comment: Oh dear, VCC had some flaws. Thanks for pointing them out. And for your feedback :)

Comment: PS do you really need the transistors for the LEDs? IME a few mA will light a LED up just fine, even a bog-standard one rated for 20 mA, so I's just connect the LEDs to the IO pins with somewhat larger resistors (for instance 1k).

Comment: I don't use transistors if the outputs are only used for LEDs. But in this case the outputs are also available in the DB9 connector, indicated by the air-wires; for things like relays, power transistors and in this case the actual fan :)

Comment: OK, fair. In that case I would include diodes, or use an ULN2003 (which has the diodes and base resistors built-in).

Comment: I always add flyback diodes directly across relays when I use them. I have a couple of ULN2001A, looks like they don't have the base resistor though. Thanks for the tip; that will save space on the board as well :)

Comment: 2001 is the version without a base resistor (add one yourself to suit your needs), 2003/2803 is the jelleybean part for 5V input.

Comment: Great, I'll include a few of those in my next order :)

Comment: @hebron why not name the net after the voltage? In our designs we have a net called 3V and one called 3Va (a for analog, which isn't self explaining) that makes is very clear and quite easy to spot problems.

Answer (score 1):

For manufacturing purposes, everything on the PCB should appear somewhere on the schematic. Where I worked this included not just the power supply and all connectors but pseudo-components for test pads, mounting holes, etc.

That doesn't necessarily mean it needs to be on the same page as the core functionality, you can park it all at the end of a multi-page schematic.

Answer (score 1):

If it's part of the circuit, it should be in the schematic. Period. Independent and complete modules that have independent schematics don't need it (ie the lcd back light is part of the lcd on the A C pins), but if it's part of your circuit it should.